# Execute command before bringing interface up on OpenWRT

Tags: networking, openwrt, mobile, chat-command

I'm making a Wireless-to-3g router with openwrt, and its working pretty well. To bring the 3g-wan interface up, I have to first register the USB modem using the command:

```
gcom -d /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If I don't do this, `chat` will fail to establish connection with `modem not registered` errors.

**My question**: Is there an option similar to `pre-up`on Debian to execute things before bringing an interface up, and only bring this up after successfully reaching this condition? Why? Because putting the `gcom` command on `/etc/rc.local` seems not to work, and it isn´t elegant.

My current `wan` interface configuration:

```
config interface 'wan'
        # === Conexão com a 3G da tim
        # option ifname ppp0
        option ifname 3g-wan
        option username tim
        option password tim
        option pincode XXXX
        option proto 3g
        option service umts
        option device /dev/ttyUSB0
        option dialnumber '*99***1#'
        option apn tim.br
```

This solution must have an out-of-the-box experience because, after configured we deliver those boxes to users to create "remote offices" on distant places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` is usually the last script run.  Look at the other scripts in `/etc/init.d` for a model to load the driver.  Something like the `firewall` script might work well.

`/etc/rc.local` contents:

```
gcom -d /dev/ttyUSB0
sleep 30
ifup wan
exit 0
```

This will register the modem, wait for a little time(30 seconds seems to be fair, as sometimes it takes 20 seconds to register on poor quality connections) and bring `wan` up.

Comment: It seems that i'll have to do that way. Since `rc.local` is the last script, `/dev/ttyUSB0` is already "busy" because it´s trying to bring `3g-wan` up by the `network` daemon and i can´t register the modem.

Comment: Well, after some time i found that using `rc.local` was the real deal. But, i added some commands and i'll edit your answer adding them, and accept your answer